# Setting foreignKey of Ember Data model

Tags: ember-data

It looks like during Revision 3 of Ember Data 1, [you could set the foreign key](https://github.com/elliterate/ember-data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md#json-keys-automatically-de-camelize):

```
App.Model = DS.Model.extend({
  namingConvention: {
    // LOUD NAMING CONVENTION
    // Changes fooKey to FOOKEY
    keyToJSONKey: function(key) {
      return key.toUpperCase();
    },

    // Determines the name of foreign keys in
    // belongsTo relationships
    foreignKey: function(key) {
      return key.toUpperCase()+"_ID";
    }
  }
});
```

That does not seem to work now (currently Revision 7). How do you set the foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for `keyForBelongsTo`. See http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  keyForBelongsTo: function(type, name) {
    return this.keyForAttributeName(type, name) + "_id";
  },
});
```